# How do I remove a feature from a SimpleFeatureCollection?

Tags: geotools

I have a SimpleFeatureCollection (sfc), now I would like to remove an object (states.32) from that collection. Is that possible?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is create a filter and then use that to create a subcollection.

So first a [filter](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/main/filter.html):

```
FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();
Set<FeatureId> fids = new HashSet<>();
fids.add(ff.featureId("states.32"));
Filter filter = ff.not(ff.id(fids));
```

Note the `not` as we want all the features that are **not** number 32.

Then to get a subcollection:

```
SimpleFeatureCollection nFeatures = features.subCollection(filter);
```

Obviously, this can be used with any `filter` and for most of them it may be easier to create it from a [CQL string](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/cql/index.html).

Putting it all together:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put(GeoPkgDataStoreFactory.DBTYPE.key, GeoPkgDataStoreFactory.DBTYPE.sample);
params.put(GeoPkgDataStoreFactory.DATABASE.key, "/home/ian/Data/geopackages/states1.gpkg");
DataStore ds = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
SimpleFeatureSource fs = ds.getFeatureSource(ds.getTypeNames()[0]);
SimpleFeatureCollection features = fs.getFeatures();
Set<FeatureId> fids = new HashSet<>();
FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();
fids.add(ff.featureId("states.32"));
Filter filter = ff.not(ff.id(fids));
SimpleFeatureCollection nFeatures = features.subCollection(filter);
System.out.println("before " + features.size() + " after " + nFeatures.size());
```

and the output is:

```
before 49 after 48
```

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm!